# Link share on facebook take server default page

Tags: wordpress, html, facebook-graph-api, plesk, facebook-share

When i am sharing my web link http://www.pk21-music.com/ which is already hosted on plesk
on facebook, Its take auto server default page,

I remove root index.html
I set robots.txt to allow all
I set Facebook all og properties
Still not work,

Here is my screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help to fix this

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.pk21-music.com/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="PK21 music" />
<meta property="og:description" content="pk21 music" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

Comment: Facebook prefers IPv6 over IPv4. Make sure your AAAA record for the domain points to the right IPv6 address, and that it is actually reachable via IPv6.

Comment: Wow.. its work now.. thank you so much for quick answer. I stuck for 6 hour and you really save my day.